# I have problems with the responsiveness of my blog

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, blogger

I have set my image "img" w=100% h=100%
but the

so the image is stretched up
can you look here, please
(FIXED)

can you tell me what's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Really unclear question. You edited out the link to your blog, but should keep a screenshot of the code itself for historic purposes rather than editing it out. It's impossible to understand now.

Comment: okie thanks.. I will add in a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this code....not stretched. If you made an image set height and width 100% it stretched out an proportionally.

```
   img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: oh thanks.. ! it works, whew... I thought it was because of some javascripts I put on it. Thank you.

Comment: @StannStee so can you accept the answer so that it will help others...thanks

Comment: its says "7 minutes" :3 .. Im waiting for it.

Comment: when I click the -check- icon it says "you can accept an answer in 7 minutes"